# Prevent resizing of images in ImpressPages 4.x

Tags: image, impresspages

Whenever I add an image using the image widget in ImpressPages 4.2.5, the image is resized to the actual width of the parent container. However, as I use a responsive design, I need the image in full resolution. Otherwise, the images will look blurry on high dpi screens (e.g. Smartphones or Retina screens).

Is there a way to prevent the image widget from resizing the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to increase the image size in theme options (`theme.json`).

Another option is to create a new skin for that widget to output original image and not resized one. Here's an article about skins - http://www.impresspages.org/docs/widgets#skin

Comment: When you change theme.json, you have to re-install the theme. That could be done by installing another theme and then installing the original one again.

Comment: Many thanks for your answers. I was able to resolve the issue with the help of your tips. Unfortunately, I have overlooked that it was the height of the image that reached my defined max value. I always focused on the width.